# Get list of sql azure databases in a Windows Azure server

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there a simple way to code in c# to get the list of Sql Azure databases in a Windows Azure server?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Just in case you're interested, you can do this action from PowerShell fairly easily - I just documented how in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585877/272109).

Answer (score 2):

To list databases on a server, you can query the sys.databases table in the master database. You can use any data access framework you like to query this table, such as Entity Framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx).

You can also list all servers under your subscription using the Management API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715269).

Comment: Thanks. However the only tables that I see in the master database are sysdac_history_internal and sysdac_instances_internal. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Sorry, I meant sys.databases view (not table). Try "SELECT * FROM sys.databases" in SQL Server Management Studio. It should work. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951625.aspx for more information.