# Azure SQL Server REST APIs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any Azure SQL server rest APIs are available for doing the following?:

1. Read Manage URL,Total Database Count and Status
2. Change subscription
3. Configuring Server

Or please let me know even if Powershell cmdlets are available.  I searched a lot and it does not seem to be available.  Please let me know ho to implement these.

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715283.aspx. There's a REST API to do some management operations.

Comment: What about the server do you want to configure? how do you want to change the subscription?  These questions are pretty vague.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell has several functions to manage SQL Database. See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17585877/272109) for an example of enumerating servers and databases. You'll be able to sum the count of servers or databases in a server.

Then, in your PowerShell command window, type `get-help *azuresql*` to see all the other commands, including `New-AzureSqlDatabase` and `Remove-AzureSqlDatabase`.

As far as changing subscription, you can run `Get-AzureSubscription` to see all subscriptions installed via import of your publish settings file. Look at each item's `SubscriptionName`. To choose that subscription, just run `Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName xxx`."

I don't know what you mean by "read manage URL."

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response David Makogon