# Azure SQL DB find all Tables in all Databases

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Perhaps this is not even possible but I am interested in seeing all Tables across all my Azure SQL DB Databases.

I can use sys.databases to get a list of Databases and sys.tables to get a list of Tables but cannot seem to figure out the correct combination to return Tables per Database.

Is this possible in Azure using straight T-SQL?  If not, is there a practicable alternative?

Comment: Please see David Makogon answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584084/get-a-list-of-all-resources-in-my-azure-subscription-powershell-preferably/17585877#17585877

Comment: Did you problem has been solved? I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved.  Do I understand correctly that the solution you provided uses PowerShell?

Comment: @Lee Liu - Please see my response from 2 days ago.

Comment: I didn't use PowerShell, i just used C# code about ADO.NET to execute T-SQL command straightly and then display the results on the web page。

Answer (score 0):

We can use straight T-SQL in Azure SQL DB.

According to your requirements, I have some demos for your reference:

**Get all tables in a specify data base:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// get all Tables in a data base
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DataBaseName">For example: MyDataBase1</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult QueryAllTables(string DataBaseName)
    {
        ContentResult content = new ContentResult();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:dotxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog="+ DataBaseName + ";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "select id,name from sysobjects where xtype='U'"; 
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string tableInfo  = "id:"+reader[0].ToString()+ " name:"+reader[1].ToString();
                    content.Content += tableInfo + "\r\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                content.Content = "No Table";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            content.Content = ex.Message;
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

**Get all tables from each data base**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// get all data bases' names
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> QueryAllDbName()
    {
        ContentResult content = new ContentResult();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:xxxxxxx.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DotNetAppSqlDb20180410043804_db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM SysDatabases ORDER BY Name";
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string DbName = reader[0].ToString();
                        list.Add(DbName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    list = null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                content.Content = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }


    public ActionResult QueryAllTablesFromEachDb()
    {
        ContentResult content = new ContentResult();
        List<string> DbNames = QueryAllDbName();
        foreach (string DbName in DbNames)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog="+ DbName + ";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    content.Content += "DataBase Name: " + DbName + "\r\n";
                    command.CommandText = "select id,name from sysobjects where xtype='U'";
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string tableInfo = "     Table id:" + reader[0].ToString() + " Table name:" + reader[1].ToString();
                            content.Content += tableInfo + "\r\n";
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    content.Content = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]